# Text label missing on some collection view cells

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uicollectionview

The problem is that the text labels are missing on some cells and when I click the like button, the text label is supposed to update the label but instead, the whole collection view disappears. The text labels are fetching the numbers from firebase.

[image: Here's a picture of what I mean]

Here is the relevant code:

HomeController.swift:

```
class HomeController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, HomePostCellDelegate {

var hpc: HomePostCell!

let cellId = "cellId"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    collectionView?.register(HomePostCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)

}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! HomePostCell
    self.hpc = cell

    cell.post = posts[indexPath.item]
    cell.delegate = self

    return cell
}

@objc func reload(likesLabelNotification: Notification) {

    guard let likesLabel = likesLabelNotification.userInfo?["likesLabelInfo"] as? UILabel else { return }
    guard let indexPath = collectionView?.indexPath(for: hpc) else { return }

    let post = self.posts[indexPath.item]
    guard let postId = post.id else { return }
    let postUserId = post.user.uid

    let numOfLikesRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("likes").child(postId)

    numOfLikesRef.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot!) in
        likesLabel.isHidden = false

        let numOfChildrens = snapshot.childrenCount
        likesLabel.text = "\(numOfChildrens)"

    }, withCancel: { (error) in
        print("failed to fetch num of posts: ",error)
    })
    self.posts[indexPath.item] = post

    self.collectionView?.reloadData()
}

func didPressShareButton(for cell: HomePostCell) {

    guard let indexPath = collectionView?.indexPath(for: cell) else { return }

    let post = self.posts[indexPath.item]
    guard let url = NSURL(string: post.videoUrl) else { return }
    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(
        activityItems: ["Check out this video I found on Vlogger: \(url)"],applicationActivities: nil)

    present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func didLike(for cell: HomePostCell) {

    guard let indexPath = collectionView?.indexPath(for: cell) else { return }

    var post = self.posts[indexPath.item]

    guard let postId = post.id else { return }

    guard let uid = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid else { return }

    let values = [uid : post.hasLiked == true ? 0 : 1]

    FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("likes").child(postId).updateChildValues(values) { (err, _) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Failed to like post", err)
            return
        }

        post.hasLiked = !post.hasLiked

        self.posts[indexPath.item] = post

        self.collectionView?.reloadData()
    }
}
```

HomePostCell.swift:

```
protocol HomePostCellDelegate {
    func didLike(for cell: HomePostCell)
}

class HomePostCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    var delegate: HomePostCellDelegate?

    lazy var likeButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "heart_unselected").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleLike), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()


    @objc func handleLike() {
        delegate?.didLike(for: self)
    }

    lazy var likesLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Regular", size: 20)
        label.textColor = UIColor.black
        label.isHidden = true
        let userInfo = ["likesLabelInfo": label]
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "refresh"), object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)
        return label
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

    }
    static let homePostCellNotificationName = NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "homePostCellRaw")

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Please comment below if you have any questions! 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: when you load first it shows ? or its only disappear on like button press ?

Comment: When I load first it shows some collection view cells and when I click the like button, the whole collection view disappears

Comment: Can you please share the code where you are adding likeButton and likesLabel to the cell? Also, I couldn't understand the need of notification of initialization.

Comment: LIKE label and like button you are creating in storyboard first time? if you are creating in story board then issue is with your  this code lazy var likesLabel: UILabel . , you are creating a new label after every tap

Comment: I removed the unnecessary code for notifications! I'm creating the likes button & label programmatically without storyboard @ShauketSheikh

Comment: can you use didLike delegate method to update label ? instead of notification , get label from your cell and update it.

Comment: change the font to smaller, and try again. maybe it was wrapped down.